can't compile anymore with poco 1.13
I'm not a developer.
Under gentoo, I used to compile https://github.com/codayblue/libmyemail with the different versions of poco from version 1.9.0-r2 to version 1.12.4.
But since the last update to version 1.13.3, the compilation fails with the error:
/usr/local/src/libmyemail/build # LANG=C make
[50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/myemail.dir/myemail.cc.o
In file included from /usr/include/Poco/Net/Net.h:23,
 from /usr/include/Poco/Net/NetSSL.h:23,
 from /usr/include/Poco/Net/SecureSMTPClientSession.h:21,
 from /usr/local/src/libmyemail/source/myemail.cc:23:
/usr/include/Poco/Foundation.h:98:22: error: 'literals' is not a namespace-name
 98 | using namespace std::literals;
 | ^~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/myemail.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/myemail.dir/myemail.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/myemail.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2


Do you have an idea for adapting myemail in order to continue compiling with this version please?

std::literals requires C++14.  Check the compiler flags for the selected C++ Standard.  Try changing set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) to set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) in codayblue / libmyemail / CMakeLists.txt  you might need to change it in other parts of the build as well.

@RichardCritten I blame myself because I had searched in this direction, and I had never seen this 11. In all the rest a grep had given me 14 and 17. Thank you very much!
